# How to disable autofill for antd input with react

Tags: reactjs, input, autocomplete, field, antd

Hello i tried to create a new form to add new user, this form contain an input `'username'` & another one `'password'`, my probleme is when i open the form the field username and password  get by default the user and password saved in browser , i tried to user `autoComplete='false'` but it doesn't work.

My question is how to disable this feature, any hint can be helpfull

This is how it looks
[image: this is how it looks]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adding `autoComplete="new-password"` to the **Input.Password**

```
<Input.Password placeholder="Mot de Passe" autoComplete="new-password" />
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Does this still work for you @salah-ed

Comment: are you sur that you have the same problem as me ? because it works perfectly in my code

Comment: Yes, I want to add one thing though if I have multiple passwords saved, then the browser is confused to autoFill the password. In that case, the password is not auto-filled. But if I just had one single password then it is being filled in automatically. Can you check if you have multiple passwords saved for this form?

Comment: no i have only one password, so you want to fill automaticlly  the password in that input when you have multiple passwords saved?

Comment: No. I don't want my passwords to auto-fill in any case. I am using <Input.Password> inside antd <Form/> component. Is that causing this issue?

Comment: My need is to remove the autofill not to fill automaticlly

Comment: Same for me as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249037/discussion-between-gana-and-salah-ed).

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of the browsers ignore these attributes autoComplete.

please check this [Ans of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tags)

Comment: yes i checked it and i tried what they said befor publishing this question

Comment: There is an idea if you make the field name dynamic then it can be misleading to browses.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was facing the same dilemma and I just used a walkaround that feels like the easier thing to do. So will leave it here in case some one else wants a quick solution to this issue.

Just use inital or default values

```
<Form
...
initialValues={{ email: '', password: '', <<any field>>: '' }}
...
>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work